# Top part of the form is cut out on small screens after I put RelativeLayout inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have RelativeLayout inside ScrollView. On small screens top part of the form is cut out (please find screenshots below). In my particular example label "Email" is totally hidden on first screen (320x240).

Do you have any idea, how to fix it?

p.s. UPD: Form controls must be center vertically.

[image: Screenshot from different screen sizes]

Layout:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblName" android:text="@string/user_email"></TextView>
            <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edEmail">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lblPassword" android:text="@string/user_password"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:id="@+id/edPassword"></EditText>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkRememberMe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/remember_me"></CheckBox>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/login"></Button>
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                    android:text="@string/register"></Button>
                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/restore_password"
                    android:id="@+id/btnRestorePassword"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/register_prompt"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="10dip" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip" android:gravity="center"              
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblName" android:text="Email" android:gravity="left"/>           
        <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edEmail">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblPassword" android:text="Password"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/edPassword"></EditText>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkRememberMe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Remeber Me"></CheckBox>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Login"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:text="Register"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Restore"
                android:id="@+id/btnRestorePassword"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Register is a simple 
            login. Just enter username and password."></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to resolve it. Sorry, I forgot to mention that controls must be centered vertically.

Comment: add  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" to the outer linearlayout.